# Azure search lookup key

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I don`t see in search results any 'key' that I can use in [Lookup document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lookup-document).

Can somebody point me how I can fetch it in search results?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I've found it. It`s not the name of a field. This is an attribute in index. You can find what field name have that attribute on Azure portal -> Fields